# iphone - question about over-releasing

Tags: iphone, memory-management, memory-leaks

In any iphone template UIViewController class you will see this:

```
- (void)viewDidUnload {

    // Release any retained subviews of the main view.
    // e.g. self.myOutlet = nil;
}
```

But if I set self.myOutlet = nil in viewDidUnload, and I also have [self.myOutlet release] in the dealloc method, isn't that over-releasing self.myOutlet, since setting it to nil will already set its retain count to zero?

If I don't release it in dealloc(), Leaks reports a memory leak because it never sees self.myOutlet getting released, assuming I have something like this in the header file:

```
@property (nonatomic, retain) UIView *myOutlet;
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you set `self.myOutlet` to `nil` in `viewDidUnload`, the call in `dealloc` to `[myOutlet release]` will simply send a release message to `nil`. It's perfectly acceptable to send messages to `nil`. Nothing bad will happen and you won't over-release anything.

The thing to watch out for is releasing the object referenced by `myOutlet` in `viewDidUnload` *without* setting `myOutlet` to `nil`. In this case, you'll get a crash in `dealloc`. Why? Because `myOutlet` will still be referring to the memory location once occupied by the `myOutlet` object, and your `dealloc` method will try to send whatever is currently at that memory location a `release` message.

Comment: Thanks guys. That's what I was hoping to hear.

Answer (score 1):

`-(void)viewDidUnload` is called when a memory warning is issued, `-(void)dealloc` is called in the complete **destruction** of a view (these aren't the same).  Therefore, you should be doing both

```
- (void)viewDidUnload {

    // Release any retained subviews of the main view.
    self.myOutlet = nil;
} 
- (void)dealloc {
    [self.myOutlet release];
}
```

**Edit: What James said furthers the point.**

Cheers!

Answer (score 1):

It's not the variable that has a retain count; it's the object. When you do `self.something = nil`, it does indeed release the object — and it sets the variable to point to `nil`. So any further `release` messages sent to `self.something` do not go to the original object. Instead, they go to the new value, `nil`, which happily ignores anything you tell it.